# Counting the length of numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to validate if the string is  less than 11.

```
var contact = Number(document.getElementById('field').value);
if(Math.floor(contact) == contact){
    if(contact.toString().length < 11){
    alert("< 11");
    }
    else{
    alert("> 11");
    }
}
```

First i will check if contact is a valid number, then if it is a number, i will count if it is less than 11. The value of the field must be numbers and it is working when i input 11111111111, but it is not working when it has 0 on it 011111111111. What is wrong in my code? thanks.

Comment: What "not working" means? PS: `contact` is a string already

Comment: if you cast it to integer, shouldn't 011111111111 be 11111111111?

Comment: @zerkms when i input 11 numbers it will alert but when i input 11 numbers including 0 it is not alerting.

Comment: @JL Dela Cruz: it's not possible for this code to not alert

Comment: it should work. Please check your `contact` if it gets a right value

Comment: @UserProg i deited the question

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/s8urkpe7/ as both of the input value you given in the question are alerting "> 11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
var contact = document.getElementById('#field').value;
```

with this

```
var contact = document.getElementById('field').value;
```

jquery has confused programmers

---

```
var contact = document.getElementById('field').value;
if(Math.floor(contact) == contact * 1){
    if(contact.length < 11){
    alert("< 11");
    }
    else{
    alert("> 11");
    }
}
```